# How to draw horizontal bullet with lines

Tags: css

I am trying to display Bullets and lines in horizontal using CSS.

```
text1             text2             textN
bullet ---line--- bullet2 ---line--- bulletN
text2             text2              textN
```

[image]

please any expert help me.

Comment: Please add whatever code you have tried so far.

Comment: Add a sample image

Comment: Please Share a example design...

Comment: @SelvaSupriyaVS added a sample image.

Comment: @SunilRajput Please check example.

Comment: check [this](https://codepen.io/jessyca27/pen/vGoBex) out as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714885/how-to-display-horizontal-timeline-using-css).

Comment: @Swati Thanks it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container{
  display:flex
}
.text{
  color:#999;
  font-family: arial
}
.textbox1{
  width:100px;
  text-align:center
}
.box{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  
  background:#fff
}
.line{
  position:relative;
}
.line::before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-bottom:1px dashed grey;
  width:80px;
  height:1px;
  top:10px;
  left:20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textbox1">
    <div class="text">sample</div>
    <div class="box line"></div>
    <div class="text">sample</div>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox1">
    <div class="text">sample</div>
    <div class="box line"></div>
    <div class="text">sample</div>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox1">
    <div class="text">sample</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="text">sample</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```